# symfony json api for loop empty

Tags: php, json, foreach, symfony

I'm trying to get data from an API in symfony. 
here's my code:

```
$champion_details_json = file_get_contents('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?api_key=mykey');

$obj2 = json_decode($champion_details_json);
$championDetailData = $obj2->data;


return $this->render('default/action.html.twig', compact('championData', 'championDetailData'));
```

Here's what a var dump shows me on the screen:

```
object(stdClass)[386]
public 'Thresh' => 
object(stdClass)[385]
  public 'id' => int 412
  public 'key' => string 'Thresh' (length=6)
  public 'name' => string 'Thresh' (length=6)
  public 'title' => string 'the Chain Warden' (length=16)
public 'Aatrox' => 
object(stdClass)[387]
  public 'id' => int 266
  public 'key' => string 'Aatrox' (length=6)
  public 'name' => string 'Aatrox' (length=6)
  public 'title' => string 'the Darkin Blade' (length=16)
```

Here's what the api's tells me i get back:

```
{
"data": {
  "Aatrox": {
     "id": 266,
     "title": "the Darkin Blade",
     "name": "Aatrox",
     "key": "Aatrox"
  },
  "Thresh": {
     "id": 412,
     "title": "the Chain Warden",
     "name": "Thresh",
     "key": "Thresh"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `json_decode($champion_details_json, true);` 
`true` flag returns array instead of object